# Profiling a running iOS app without a computer attached

Tags: iphone, profiling

I would like to profile a running app without a computer attached. Pretty much what the `sample` command does on Mac OS X. Is it possible ?

I would like to do this without any computer attached because my app gets into an endless loop only at certain GPS locations. I tried reproducing the problem by faking GPS fixes but I couldn't. Yet the issue is 100% reproductible in the field…

Answer (score 3):

You can try logging suspected method and loop entry/exits to a file, and recover the file later using iTunes Document sharing or Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

No - I'm pretty sure it isn't, as Apple does not allow developers to use **any** iOS-development tools on the platform itself. You might be able to build analytical stuff into your own app (RAM monitor etc.), but not by using another app.

Anyway, your computer is much better suited to the task than a device - so sick with it.

Maybe some day Apple will let us test/write iPhone apps from iPads...